# React Double array statement UI

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to show the comment array in the UI using the regid and the comment map. What should I do. Help

I have an array inside an array, so I don't know how to make it visible in the UI.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, @김민수 welcome to SO. Try using the syntax snippets the next time you ask a question, and show a little bit more about what you tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have array inside an array, you will need two loops or two map statements to ensure that the same is returned. Below I have tried to take a similar object as yours to show how it should look like

```js
// assuming you have below object
const obj = {
  product: {
    Comments: [
      {
        User: { regId: 1, content: "Comment 1 Content" }
      },
      {
        User: { regId: 2, content: "Comment 2 Content" }
      }
    ]
  }
}

const renderComments = obj.product.Comments.map(({ User: { regId, content }) => <label>{regId}: {content});
```

Comment: I did as the teacher told me. But I get an error.   code Added const renderComments = Object.product.Comments.map({ User: { regId, content } })
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Comments' of undefined I get an error

Comment: Your `object` structure is different. I will advise to read basics of destructuring before you start using it. Can you check how your object structure is.

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer if it worked well for you, thanks :)